# How to save existing objects to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have been working on a project and have an existing object I am using. I am trying to find a simply way to save, retrieve and delete a list of these objects in Core Data.

Here is my object

```
import Foundation

class Book : Codable {

    var coverIndex:Int?
    var authorName:[String]?
    var title:String?
    var editionCount:Int?
    var firstPublishYear:Int?
    var key: String?
    var publishPlace:[String]?
    var publisher:[String]?

    public enum BookResponseCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case coverIndex = "cover_i"
        case authorName = "author_name"
        case editionCount = "edition_count"
        case firstPublishYear = "first_publish_year"
        case key = "key"
        case title = "title"
        case publishPlace = "publish_place"
        case publisher = "publisher"
    }

    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: BookResponseCodingKeys.self)

        self.coverIndex = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .coverIndex)
        self.authorName = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .authorName)
        self.editionCount = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .editionCount)
        self.firstPublishYear = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .firstPublishYear)
        self.key = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .key)
        self.title = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.publishPlace = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .publishPlace)
        self.publisher = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .publisher)
    }
}
```

What is the most straightforward to save this in Core Data (or to map it to a Core Data model.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your `xcdatamodeld` define an entity, such as `User`:

[image]

Add an attribute with a Transformable type. Name it 'books'.

[image]

Next, set the Transformable attribute's class to an array of Book. In the `Custom Class` field below.

[image]

Use the following code to get the current array from your current context. These methods should go in some sort of DataManager class (which should be a singleton):

```
import CoreData

open class DataManager: NSObject {
    
    public static let sharedInstance = DataManager()
    
    private override init() {}

    // Helper func for getting the current context.
    private func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext? {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return nil }
        return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    func retrieveUser() -> NSManagedObject? {
        guard let managedContext = getContext() else { return nil }
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "User")
        
        do {
            let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest) as! [NSManagedObject]
            if result.count > 0 {
                // Assuming there will only ever be one User in the app.
                return result[0]
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Retrieving user failed. \(error): \(error.userInfo)")
           return nil
        }
    }

    func saveBook(_ book: Book) {
        print(NSStringFromClass(type(of: book)))
        guard let managedContext = getContext() else { return }
        guard let user = retrieveUser() else { return }
        
        var books: [Book] = []
        if let pastBooks = user.value(forKey: "books") as? [Book] {
            books += pastBooks
        }
        books.append(book)
        user.setValue(books, forKey: "books")
        
        do {
            print("Saving session...")
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to save session data! \(error): \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }

}
```

You'll also need a method to create a user (and likely delete, assuming we want to follow CRUD). First, you'll need to grab a reference to the User Entity to create one. This definition should be at the top of your DataManager class.

```
extension DataManager {
    private lazy var userEntity: NSEntityDescription = {
        let managedContext = getContext()
        return NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User", in: managedContext!)!
    }()
}
```

And then implement this function to create one.

```
extension DataManager {
    /// Creates a new user with fresh starting data.
    func createUser() {
        guard let managedContext = getContext() else { return }
        let user = NSManagedObject(entity: userEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Failed to save new user! \(error): \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Now just call:

`DataManager.sharedInstance.createUser()`

to create a new user.
Then, to append books to the user's storage:

`DataManager.sharedInstance.saveBook(book)`

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I get the error I was afraid of: Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C in this class : User+CoreDataProperties.swift

Comment: Just noticed this. Instead of subclassing `Codable`, try subclassing `NSObject` and `NSCoding` instead. Make sure to implement the `encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)` and the `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` methods.

Comment: NSObject and Codable seems to work. Let me try the rest.

Comment: cool. I assume for the variable sessions you mean books. So from an external class whats the order of calls?

Comment: Woops, yes I did. First, just call ```createUser()```. That only needs to run once - in fact you can check to make sure a User hasn't already been created by checking whether ```retrieveUser()``` returns nil. Then save your books with ```saveBook(book)``` method. With this current function, you'd have to do so one-by-one, but it should be quite simple to make a function for appending a batch.

Comment: Ah so user should be a singleton as well.

Comment: Idk if it's possible to implement a singleton pattern in a CoreData entity. What I meant is that whatever class holds all of these methods (e.g. 'DataManager') should be a singleton, and be called through a `sharedInstance`.

Comment: Ok trying it out. Currently it's failing to load the data model.

Comment: Edit: Implemented the singleton pattern in my answer.

Comment: Wow it works! You are right I cannot use Codable I have to use NSCoding.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to work with your object. You could inherit your object from NSManagedObject or establish mapping from NSManagedObject consisting your object data to your class.

If you won't inherit your object from NSManagedObject, you could use code like this:

```
func save(bookObject: Book, in container: NSPersistentContainer) -> NSManagedObject {
        container?.performBackgroundTask { context in
            do {
                // Create NSManagedObject backed object
                let bookEntity = BookEntity(context: context)
                bookEntity.coverIndex = bookObject.coverIndex
                // And all the rest properties

                try context.save()
            } catch (let error) {
                print(error)
                return
            }

        }
    }
```