# how to store [UIImage] into Core Data and retrieve to [UIImage] from binary date

Tags: swift, core-data

my code is like these:

```
     //save to core data  
     func addPaper(){
        let paper = Paper(context: self.context)
        
        paper.id = UUID()
        paper.subject = self.subject
        paper.score = Float(self.score) ?? 0
        paper.title = self.title
        let imgs = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.images, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        paper.images = imgs
        try? self.context.save()
    }
//retrieve to [UIImage]


  let imgs = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: [UIImage], from: paper.images!)
```

there is an error tip:Static method 'unarchivedObject(ofClass:from:)' requires that '[UIImage]' conform to 'NSCoding'

I don't know what to do next, can anyone give me some help?

Comment: you should not store image in coredata ... store them in directory and save url path in coredata

Comment: You can't transform like that a UIImage into Data with NSKeyedArchiver. Shouldn't this throw an error first? You need to use JPEG or PNG transformation, then you will have Data.

Comment: no error when save to core data,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you need this, any object can be saved to core data.
:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56453857/how-to-save-existing-objects-to-core-data

I copied the following steps from others, hope it helps

1.making your custom types (Exercise) subclass of NSObject

2.setting the attribute's type in the core data model to Transformable

3.setting the CustomClass to [Exercise]

Answer (score 1):

You should not store image in CoreData. Maybe store in base64 format, and you can encode/decode whenever you want.

**Base64 To image:**

```
func base64ToImage(data: String) -> Data{
    let encodedImageData = data
    let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: encodedImageData)
        
    return imageData!
 }

imageView.image = UIImage(data: dataDecoded)
```

**Image to base64**

```
func imageToBase64(image: UIImage) -> String {
    return image.pngData()!
        .base64EncodedString()
}
```

Comment: i think you post solution in swift 3

Comment: Thank you, it was an old snippet :)

Comment: I want to store the whole array with UIImage

Comment: can I store any Object into CoreData?